# Is K-W test statistics a U statistics?

Tags: anova, nonparametric, asymptotics, u-statistics

The K-W H test statistic is given by:

$$
H=(N-1) \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{g} n_{i}\left(\bar{r}_{i \cdot}-\bar{r}\right)^{2}}{\sum_{i=1}^{g} \sum_{j=1}^{n_{i}}\left(r_{i j}-\bar{r}\right)^{2}}, \text { where: }
$$
If the data contain no ties
$$
H=\frac{12}{N(N+1)} \sum_{i=1}^{g} n_{i}\left(\bar{r}_{i}-\frac{N+1}{2}\right)^{2}
$$$$
=\frac{12}{N(N+1)} \sum_{i=1}^{g} n_{i} \bar{r}_{i .}^{2}-3(N+1)
$$

It extends the Mann–Whitney U test (also called Wilcoxon rank sum test) , which is used for comparing only two groups. I learned that Mann–Whitney U statistic is U statistic. I want to know is  K-W test statistics a U statistics?

The Kruskal–Wallis test is also called one-way ANOVA on ranks. Is one-way ANOVA (not on rank) a U statistics?

Comment: Neither neither of them seem to be U-statistics if there are more than 2 groups.

Comment: See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%E2%80%93Wallis_one-way_analysis_of_variance) on K-W tests. Often the test statistic $H$ has approximately a chi-squared distribution.

Comment: @BruceET Yes，it is also why I think that's U statistics.